# Mongoose error Unsupported projection option: sort: { createdAt: -1 }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to sort my mongoose entries by date, most recent first in node.js express with mongoose.

the mongoose query is:

```
  FecalRequest.findOne({uid: req.user.id}, {sort:{'createdAt':-1}}, (err, fecalkits) => {
    console.log(fecalkits);
    done(err, respiratorykits, fecalkits)
  });
```

I've tried both created_at and createdAt. The error is 
eMongoError: Unsupported projection option: sort: { createdAt: -1 }

For reference, the FecalRequest model looks like:

```
const fecalSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    uid: String,
    email: String,
    status: {type: String, default: 'No Request' },
  },
  { timestamps: true });
```

I just want to return the most recently made entry for a particular user.

Answer (score 19):

Include an empty object as a second (projection) parameter so that your third parameter to [`findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) is properly interpreted as query options:

```
FecalRequest.findOne({uid: req.user.id}, {}, {sort:{'createdAt':-1}}, (err, fecalkits) => {
  console.log(fecalkits);
  done(err, respiratorykits, fecalkits)
});
```

Definitely the most times I've used the word "fecal" in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use findOne for this.  You'd use find() with sort() and limit().

findOne is just going to return the first document found that matches your search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Mongoose, you cannot use `sort` with `findOne`. (See the [query options doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions).)

Your query would become:

```js
FecalRequest.find({uid: req.user.id}, {}, {sort: {'createdAt':-1}, limit: 1}, (err, fecalkits) => {
  console.log(fecalkits);
  done(err, respiratorykits, fecalkits);
});
```

And keep in mind this returns a list.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think its possible to sort if you're finding just one document.

I believe that "Find" is the function you should be using?